# Laravel: MethodNotAllowedHttpException error Trying to like a post

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

On my website users are allowed to create posts and like posts. I had a previous error relating to the like system before this and I managed to get that resolved. However with this error I can't figure out what it is. When a user clicks like they are presented with the following error:

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
```

This is my post controller method for the like:

```
public function postLikePost($post_id){
    $loggedin_user = Auth::user()->id;
    $like_user = Like::where(['user_id' => $loggedin_user, 'post_id' => $post_id])->first();
    if(empty($like_user->user_id)){
        $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $post_id = $post_id;

        $like = new Like;

        $like->user_id = $user_id;
        $like->post_id = $post_id;
        $like->save();
        return  redirect()->route('events');

    }else{
        return  redirect()->route('events');
    }

}
```

This is my Like model:

```
class Like extends Model
{
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function post(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
    }
}
```

This is my likes migration:

```
    Schema::create('likes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('post_id');
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

This is my route for the like:

```
Route::post('/like/{post_id}', 'PostController@postLikePost')->name('like');
```

This my view for the post:

```
<section class="row posts">
    @foreach($posts as $post)
        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-3">
            <article class="post">
                <p>{{ $post->body }}</p>
                <div class="info">Posted by {{ $post->user->first_name }} {{ $post->user->last_name }} on {{ $post->created_at }}</div>
                <p>This post has {{ $post->likes()->count() }} likes </p> 
                <a href="{{ route('like', ['post_id' => $post->id]) }}" class="post-item">Like</a>|
            </article>
        </div>
    @endforeach
</section>
```

Comment: well you are using GET instead of POST inside your blade file

Comment: Would you mind sharing with us the whole exception message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either convert the like button to a form with POST request or submit the request via Ajax as a POST request.

Alternatively, update your route to a GET request (if you want to keep the current blade template as it is):

```
Route::get('/like/{post_id}', 'PostController@postLikePost')->name('like');
```

Comment: Oh I changed it to get and it solved that issue but now I get this: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth' not found

Comment: Change this line `Auth::user()->id;` to `\Auth::user()->id;` - you have a namespace issue. Either import the namespace or use backslash like I showed. You may have to do that to the models also, e.g. `\Like` etc...

Comment: I imported the namespace and it fixed it, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The **MethodNotAllowed** error is regularly the method used in the route, for example when you want to access to a method by `GET` being `POST` and around.

In this case the error is that you are using the method `POST` but you are redirecting to the route with a tag `a` which the uses the method `GET`, so you have to change the route from `POST` to `GET` like this:

**Routes**:

```
Route::post('/like/{post_id}', 'PostController@postLikePost')->name('like');
```

**to**

```
Route::get('/like/{post_id}', 'PostController@postLikePost')->name('like');
```

That is all that you need to change, regards!

Answer (score 0):

In addition if you want to perform multiple methods on one route then you can also use below method specified by Laravel Framework.

```
Route::any('/like/{post_id}', 'PostController@postLikePost')->name('like');
```

and

```
Route::match(['GET','POST'],'/like/{post_id}', 'PostController@postLikePost')->name('like');
```